A construction of ambient isotopy in P.L. Topology
Let $I^n$ be unit cube and $h_i : I^n \rightarrow I^n , \forall i \in \{ 0,1\} $  be two homeomorphism which agree on $\partial I^n$.
Claim : $h_0$ and $h_1$ are ambient isotopic fixing $\partial I^n$.
Proof : Construct homeomorphism $ H $ of $ I^n \times I $ as follows :
$H_0= h_0$ , $ H_1 = h_1 $ ;
$H|\partial I^n \times I = (h_0|\partial I^n) \times id  $
$H(p)=p $ , where $p=(0,1/2) \in I^n \times I$   and
$H|I^n \times I $ is defined by conical extension from $x$.
This explanation was done in Introduction to Piecewise-Linear Topology by Rourke Sanderson .
What I understand is the following :
I have to construct $H : I^n \times I \rightarrow I^n \times I $ by $H (x , t )=H_t(x)$ where $H_t : I^n \times I \rightarrow I^n \times I  $ is homeomorphism such that $H_0=h_0 $, $H_1=h_1$ and $H_t| \partial I^n \times I = (h_0|\partial I^n) \times id = (h_1|\partial I^n)\times id$  as $h_0(x)=h_1(x) \forall x \in \partial I^n$.
I want to construct $H_t$ on $int (I^n \times I)$ for $0<t<1$ .
Suppose $ x \in  int (I^n \times I) $ then there is straight line joining $p$ and $y$ where $y \in \partial I^n \times I$ such that $x$ lies in the line . So $H (x ) = H( \lambda p + (1- \lambda )y ) = \lambda p + (1- \lambda ) (h_0 \times id )(y) $ .
But I could not write $H_t$ properly which is level preserving so that $H$ is isotopy . Can you please help me ?
